# Access python dic in template view with Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views

When I want to pass a dic from `views.py` to a template it is not rendered correctly.

I tried using |safe and `JSON.parse()`, however both did not solve the issue. It seems like the error could already happen in `views.py`.

---

***views.py***

```
participant_per_challenge = {}

for participant in challenge_participants:

        if str(participant.challenge.id) in participant_per_challenge:
            participant_per_challenge[str(participant.challenge.id)].append(participant.player.userid)
        else:
            participant_per_challenge[str(participant.challenge.id)] = []
            participant_per_challenge[str(participant.challenge.id)].append(participant.player.userid)


my_dict = {
 'challenges' : challenges,
 'challenge_participants' : challenge_participants,
 'unique_participants': unique_participants,
 'participant_per_challenge': participant_per_challenge,

 }

return render(request, "challengeview/index.html", context=my_dict)
```

---

here an example dic from ***views.py***

```
{
  "1": [
    "bc5ac2b77a2d4b9e90ff4aa6012a4891",
    "a61254636e5f432292459b406cf55f47"
  ],
  "2": [
    "a61254636e5f432292459b406cf55f47",
    "bc5ac2b77a2d4b9e90ff4aa6012a4891"
  ]
}
```

---

***index.html***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var player_per_challenge = "{{ participant_per_challenge|safe}}";
console.log(typeof player_per_challenge); //THIS RETURNS STRING

</script>
```

---

**Expected result:** a JSON object of which I can access parameters

---

> **Actual result:** a string. `JSON.parse()` did not work as well ("Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with JSON.parse").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encode the `dict` to a JSON in your view and use it (without quotes) in your Javascript code. For example:

**views.py**

```
import json
...
'participant_per_challenge': json.dumps(participant_per_challenge),
```

then

**index.html**

```
var player_per_challenge = {{ participant_per_challenge | safe}};
```